# What magic items from the DMG give a +1 to saving throws?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, saving-throw

My DM gave a few magic items to the party after a particularly rough encounter with a dragon a month or so ago. One player was absent, so we only had 3, and another player's character died. The result of this is that my greedy gnome criminal and the guileless half-orc fighter were the only 2 characters alive. Of course, I took all the magic items.

My DM can’t remember what one of the items was, and neither can I. All we know is it gave a +1 bonus to saving throws, and was in the DMG.

What magic items from the DMG give +1 bonus to all saving throws?

Comment: ...Is it safe to assume that when you say "one player died", you mean their character died? (And that the other player was absent, so their character was ignored/absent for the events of the session as well?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Magic items that grant a +1 to saving throws (among other benefits) include:

- [*Cloak of Protection*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/cloak-of-protection) (uncommon)
- [*Luck Blade*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/luck-blade) (legendary)
- [*Ring of Protection*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-protection) (rare)
- [*Robe of Stars*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/robe-of-stars) (very rare)
- [*Rod of Alertness*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/rod-of-alertness) (very rare)
- [*Stone of Good Luck*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/stone-of-good-luck-luckstone) (uncommon)

There are many more items than this that give advantage on saves, and one that gives a +2 to saving throws (instead of +1).

Comment: I am sorry if I seemed lazy I prefer not to search the DMG for magic items as I like being surprised as to what I’ll get and my DM is very busy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133603/discussion-between-kirt-and-oblivious-sage).

Comment: For others wondering, outside of strictly the DMG other items that boost saves include: Staff of Power, Blackstaff, Ioun Stones